# Can't access drives in WSL (Bash on Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my Bash window on Windows 10 I'm trying to access my drives using "`cd /mnt/c`" or "`cd /mnt/d`".   When I type either command it takes me to `/home`.  Is anybody else having trouble accessing their drives?

Comment: I uninstalled using "lxrun /uninstall" and re-installed: same problem.

Comment: I am able to use this activity on my laptop that runs Win10, but not on my desktop.  Strange.